# How to show random movie on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, c#-4.0, razor

I want to show random movie from AppDomain.BaseDirectory on page load.

```
  RandomVideo.cshtml 

  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="MyMovie1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> */ MyMovie1 should not be hard coded*/
  </video>
```

Comment: How do your videos are stored in BaseDirectory?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich It's like movie1,movie2,movie3 .... movie(N)

*(N) tends to number of videos dependent count available in BaseDirectory. 

Will iteration work or generate number and concatenate with video source?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

### View

```
@model VideoModel

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="@Model.VideoSource" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

### Model

```
public class VideoModel
{
    public string VideoSource { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PlayVideo()
    {
        var model = new VideoModel();

        var videos = Directory
            .GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".mp4"))
            .ToList();

        var randomVideo = videos[new Random().Next(0, videos.Count)];

        model.VideoSource = randomVideo;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: -Great! But if I try to improvise it like whenever any user approach that view there should be random video hard coding video source will not fulfill requirement, Random video(random videosource) whenever someone go to that view.

Comment: It's Working and I bit Updated the code 

var videos = Directory
            .GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .Where(f => f.EndsWith(".mp4") || f.EndsWith(".ogg") || f.EndsWith(".webM"))
            .ToList();
As it will deal for multi formats defined in Views. Nice Answer!